# NativeQuery Spring Data return object

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, nativequery

I need to implement a query in Spring Data like this :-

```
Select User.name, sum(Activity.minutes) 
From User, Activity, ActivityStatus
Where User.id = ActivityStatus.userId
And Activity.id = ActivityStatus.activityId
AND ActivityStatus = "COMPLETED"
GROUP BY user.name;
```

So i need to join 3 tables, therefore I have to use `@Query` with `nativeQuery = true` ( correct me if I'm wrong here )

And so my Repository method looks like this :-

```
@Query(value = "Select User.name, sum(Activity.minutes) as total_minutes
    From User, Activity, ActivityStatus
    Where User.id = ActivityStatus.userId
    And Activity.id = ActivityStatus.activityId
    AND ActivityStatus = "COMPLETED"
    AND User.Type = ?1
    GROUP BY user.name;",
    nativeQuery = true
    )
List<MyObj> getTotalActivityMinutesByUserType(String userType);
```

`MyObj` class looks like this :-

```
public class MyObj {
    String name;
    long total_minutes;

// getter and setter methods

    public MyObj(String name, long total_minutes) {
        this.name = name;
        this.total_minutes = total_minutes;
    }
}
```

My Test Method :-

```
@Test
public void TotalActivityTest() throws Exception {
    List<MyObj> objA = myRepository.getTotalActivityMinutesByUser("TEST");

}
```

and i get the following exception :-

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type
>   [com.mycomp.MyObj] for value '{TEST, 5.0}'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to
>   type [com.mycomp.dto.MyObj]

I need a way to return the result as `MyObj`. ( Or at least a way to cast it to MyObj) Is this possible?

EDIT:

Building from @Cepr0's answer My Entity class looks like this :-

```
@Entity
public class ActivityStatus extends Base {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    private Activity activity;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    private User user;

}
```

I am not sure how the JOIN query in JPQL should look like...

Comment: have you executed this query in db ui like sqldeveloper because where are you using joins over here to establish the relation ship?

Comment: Yes, there's no issues with the query. From the exception you can observe that the result is {TEST,5.0} which is exactly the result I get from running the query on the workbench. The problem is in mapping the result set to MyObj.

Comment: The query is returning object array which you are storing it in in an object.Iterate through object array and set it to object

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use [Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) and [JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html) query:

```
public interface NameAndDuration {
    String getName();
    Long getDuaration();
}

@Query("select u.name as name, sum(a.minutes) as duration from User u join u.activityStatus st join st.activity a where st.status = "COMPLETED" and u.type = ?1 group by u.name")
List<NameAndDuration> getNameAndDurationByUserType(String userType);

List<NameAndDuration> list = getNameAndDurationByUserType("TEST");
String userName = list.get(0).getName();
```

This query is probably not exact what you need because I don't know a structure of your entity classes. But if you show them I will correct the query...

Comment: Thanks for the help, not quite working yet. Here's how my Entity class look like :-

`@Entity
public class ActivityStatus extends Base {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    private Activity activity;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    private User user;
}`

In this case, how should i write the JOIN query in JPQL?

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry for the messy comments, but i managed to build the correct JPQL query and it worked! will try it out more tomorrow. Your answer definitely looks cleaner. so I'm marking this as the answer.

Comment: As I found the key to success is using an interface (rather than a class) and naming the result set names to match the interface. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me! The only thing to keep in mind that order of the column (in native-query) must be same for the interface. :)

Answer (score 0):

The query is returning object array which you are storing in an normal object.Iterate through object array and set it to object like below

```
List<MyObj > test= new ArrayList<>();
List<Object[]> rows= query.list();
for (Object[] row : rows) {
MyObj temp=new MyObj (arg1,arg2);
temp.set((Dataype) row[0])//You need to create getters and setters for your pojo
..
test.add(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Pradeep, I'm pretty sure your answer works as well, but I guess Cepr0's answer is cleaner. Appreciate your help though.

Comment: Glad that you are able to fix the issue.You r Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a similar issue with this exception.  I have 3 tables: Project, Asset, and ProjectAsset.  ProjectAsset is the reference table where one project can have many assets.  So I created 3 repositories, one for each entity.  The problem is I placed my @Query in the ProjectAssetRepository and that didn't work due to the repository extending CrudRepository.  ProjectAssetId is an embedded id made up of projectid and assetid.  I can't just return Asset objects in this repository so I moved the method to AssetRepository and everything worked.  If you are using cross-reference tables, make sure you pull the correct object or else you will run into this exception.